# Making a custom data structure threadsafe in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been looking into thread safety when doing multithreading. I'm looking into the use of locks to make a custom data structure threadsafe.

Is this the most suitable implementation for making this custom histogram threadsafe?

Also I'm new here. Is there a tag that I can use if I would like help tracing code to find out what it does?

**Histogram class (Unsafe)**

```
public class Histogram
{
    protected long[] bins;
    protected int min, max, range;
    protected int numBins;

    public Histogram(int max, int min, int numBins)
    {
        this.max = max;
        this.min = min;
        this.numBins = numBins;
        bins = new long[numBins];
        range = max - min + 1;
    }

    public void add(int num)
    {
        int bin = (int) Math.floor(((num - min) * 1.0 / range) * numBins);
        bins[bin]++;
    }

    public int absDifference(Histogram histogram)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        if (histogram.min == min && histogram.max == max && histogram.numBins == numBins)
            for (int i = 0; i < bins.length; i++)
                sum += (int) Math.abs(bins[i] - histogram.bins[i]);

        return sum;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String out = String.format("{Min: %d, Max: %d, # Bins: %d, Values: ", min, max, numBins);
        for (int i = 0; i < bins.length; i++)
            out += bins[i] + ", ";

        out = out.substring(0, out.length() - 2);
        out += "}";
        return out;
    }
}
```

**Thread safe Histogram class**

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;


public class HistogramSafe extends Histogram
{
    private Lock[] binLocks;

    public HistogramSafe(int max, int min, int numBins)
    {
        super(max, min, numBins);

        binLocks = new ReentrantLock[numBins];
        for (int i = 0; i < numBins; i++)
            binLocks[i] = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int num)
    {
        int bin = (int) Math.floor(((num - min) * 1.0 / range) * numBins);

        binLocks[bin].lock();
        bins[bin]++;
        binLocks[bin].unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If your `numBins` (also `min` and `max`) variable **can not change**, i.e. your data structure is of **fixed size**, then it should be **thread-safe**, allowing parallel modification of different bins.

---

But if `numBins` (or `min`, `max`) is modifiable then it's not thread-safe anymore. As you previously access `numBins` which then is also a shared resource and it is not inside **the same lock**.

It could be possible that a thread enters the method, reads `numBins` and then sleeps (due to thread scheduler). Now another thread comes and executes the full method. The old thread continues and sets `bins[bin]++`, but with an **outdated value** for `numBins`.

If you, for example, also provide a `remove` function, then this could even lead to `IndexOutOfBoundException` since the first thread may read a size of `10` and then other threads reducing the size to `5`. When the first thread continues, it may try to write to an **invalid index**.

Answer (score 1):

In order to ensure that a method is thread safe the `synchronized` keyword can be of help. Also any data structure which is immutable is **mostly** thread safe.

```
public synchronized void methodName(){}
```

as [Zabuza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411243/zabuza) said this will block all the threads which try to call the method.

Another way ensure thread safe is to make a **synchronized block** which will take as parameter an object on which you want to make the lock

```
public void methodName(){
  synchronized(object) {
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: `synchronized`, in this case, would block the whole method for all threads. OP tries to realize that threads which want to modify **different bins** can continue.

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate using AtomicInteger for your bin members.  In your example, the thread safety issue is due to the increment of an integer (read, add, write).  AtomicInteger operations are thread safe and much faster.

Synchronization and locks are better for protecting complex data structures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna look at this from a different perspective - no, in my opinion it is not thread-safe. Why? Because you allowed inheritance. A lot of things can go wrong when someone extends this class - mostly overriding the `add` method.